# R - How to 'create' or plot missing data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, missing-data

I have a datset, AIS_dat, which looks at the number of boats (BoatCount) present at three sites (Site) on different days of the week (Day), before and during a Covid lockdown.

```
rm(list = ls())
setwd('K:/SoundTrap/Boats/PSD Output/Duty cycle data/TOL analysis')
getwd()

AIS_dat<-read.csv("AllSitesConcat_dBcalcs_50-24000Hz_matchedCameraCounts.csv") 
str(AIS_dat)

#set factors
AIS_dat$Lockdown <- as.factor(AIS_dat$Lockdown)

#change order of sites
AIS_dat$Site<-factor(AIS_dat$Site, 
                     level=c('Kawau','Tiritiri','Noises'))

#change order of days
AIS_dat$Day<-factor(AIS_dat$Day, 
                     level=c('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'))

#hour of day as factor
AIS_dat$Hour <- as.factor(AIS_dat$Hour)


#Look at variation between sites
bp<-ggplot(AIS_dat, aes(x=Day,y=BoatCount,fill=factor(Site))) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  ylab(expression("Number of Boats"))+
  xlab("Day of Week")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = get_pal("Kereru"),
                    name="Site") +
  theme_bw()
bp

bp<-bp+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0,size=14),
             axis.text.y = element_text(size=14),
             axis.title.x = element_text(size=14),
             axis.title.y =element_text(size=14),
             #legend.title = element_text(size = 14),
             #legend.text = element_text(size = 14)
              ) #rotate x-axis labels

bp<-bp+facet_grid(rows=vars(Lockdown)) #separate plot for each season
bp
```

The plot looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Pbz.png)

...which is awesome. BUT, because there is no data for Tiritiri under 'During', we only see two sites, and it is a bit misleading as the order of the sites then changes. I'd like to have missing data in this panel to make it clear which site is which. How would I do this? Would I have to add missing data to my original datasheet somehow? I tried this but it didn't work, so if that is the best approach I am not sure which way to do it?

The dataset looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwvqY.png) (but has 17143 rows):

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `site` and `day` into a new column used for the x axis ticks. The function `facet` will arrange the x tick values by default in a fixed way:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1337)

before_data <-
  tribble(
  ~step, ~Site,
  "before", "K",
  "before", "T",
  "before", "N"
) %>%
  mutate(
    value = rnorm(10) %>% list()
  ) %>%
  unnest(value)

during_data <-
  tribble(
    ~step, ~Site,
    "during", "K",
    "during", "N"
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    value = rnorm(10) %>% list()
  ) %>%
  unnest(value)

data <- bind_rows(before_data, during_data) %>% mutate(day = "Monday")

data %>%
  mutate(x = paste0(day, Site)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, value, color = Site)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    facet_grid(~step)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>